# Why doesn't side diffusion raise resistance of an integrated resistor?

Tags: semiconductors, solid-state-devices

Consider forming an integrated resistor by diffusion of n+ dopants down into some p- substrate (the corresponding pn junction is reverse biased during operation). Let \$W,L,t\$ be the width, length, and thickness of this resistor nominally (i.e. on the mask), and let us deliver flux of dopants \$Q_D\$ (dopants per unit area) to the mask area \$WL\$. Nominally, we might then say that (if the implantation is done in a certain way and \$t\$ is not too large) that we have uniform doping of \$N_D = Q_D/t\$. Let us further assume that the implantation and subsequent diffusion activation is such as to cause some side and down diffusion. Let's also assume that \$W,L\$ are relatively large so that the dominant component of resistance can be computed in a 1D approximation.

Given these assumptions, my textbook (see below) says essentially that "side diffusion was [need not be] taken into account because the ohmic resistance of the...layer is determined entirely by the number of impurity atoms actually diffused." I am trying to convince myself of this claim. How do we argue for it?

Do we roughly argue that the extra diffusion in the lengthwise direction is negligible, and then proceed as follows: the total resistance of the resistor can be computed as the resistance of imagined "wires" in parallel, where we integrate them along the y (width) and x (thickness) directions. I use the subscript \$d\$ to denote quantities which have changed from their nominal values after the diffusion activation.
$$R = \left(\frac{1}{L}\int_{0}^{W_d}\int_{0}^{t_d} q \mu_n N_{Dd}(x,y) \,dx \, dy \right)^{-1}.$$
Does one now argue that, to the extent \$\mu_n\$ is independent of doping, one has that
$$\frac{1}{L}\int_{0}^{W_d}\int_{0}^{t_d} N_{Dd}(x,y) \,dx \, dy = (Q_DWL)/L^2 = N_DtW/L$$
where the above basically comes from thinking about the total number of dopants in the "bathtub". Thus we get the same \$R\$ as if we had've just used the nominal \$R = \frac{L}{q\mu_nN_DWt}\$. I am very unsure of this because assuming \$L\$ doesn't change much whereas \$W\$ does seems a bit absurd, but I couldn't stitch up an argument without doing that.

---

As an aside (and for those who have access to a copy), this question is motivated by a comment made on page 102 of the 5th edition of *Analysis and Design of Analog Integrated Circuits* by Gray, Hurst, Lewis, and Meyer, where they calculate the collector resistance of an antiquated bipolar process. The specific motivation has to do with the component of this collector resistance associated with the buried layer. They write "Here the buried-layer side diffusion was not taken into account because the ohmic resistance of the buried layer is determined entirely by the number of impurity atoms actually diffused [see (2.15)] into the silicon, which is determined by the mask dimensions and the sheet resistance of the buried layer."

Comment: I think your examples are set up oddly. First, the phrase "precision diffusion resistors" is an oxymoron - the resistors are "free" devices in the process but they'll have significant voltage and temperature coefficients. Second, edge diffusion in a resistor is easily handled in modelling by just making the device, and measuring various geometries to figure out what the edge offset is. Third, by saying "W and L are relatively large", you are minimizing the impact of the edge diffusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can argue that diffusion (both sideways and down) decreases the resistance, because mobility increases as the doping decreases. Assuming the total number of dopants remains the same, which is roughly true.

In any case the change is probably not very big, and if you really care you should simulate it.